# В чем отличие {{ data }} от {{{ data }}}

Tags: javascript, handlebars

Может кто-нибудь пояснить, в чем отличие `{{data}}` от `{{{data}}}`?

А также такая вот запись: `{{{{raw}}}}` в чем отличие от двух предыдущих?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`{{data}}` - выводит содержимое свойства `data` контекста(переданного шаблону javascript-объекта), выполняя над ним html-кодирование. Т.е. `<h1>Product</h1>` будет выведено как `&lt;h1&gt;Product&lt;/h1&gt;`. Это полезно для работы с пользовательским вводом, который по определению не безопасен.

`{{{data}}}` - выводит содержимое свойства `data` контекста, не выполняя никаких преобразований. `<h1>Product</h1>` будет выведено как `<h1>Product</h1>`.

`{{{{raw}}}}` - просто выведет текст `raw`, не обращаясь к контексту, и не проводя внутри него парсинга handlebars-выражений.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!